# I just downloaded Aptana Studio 3 in Windows 8.1 Pro with Java SDK

Tags: python

But I can't find it where it is installed. It isn't even listed at start menu, it can't be found at Program Files (64 bit) and also in Program Files (x86). I repaired installation but again no way to find.

Answer (score 0):

Try:  C:\Users\\appdata\roaming\appcelerator\

that is where I found it.  I had the same problem.  I also just put *aptan* into the search input field and let the system do its thing.

Comment: Super helpful answer! Were you able to get this application to be recognized by windows 8.1 search everywhere tool?